# devextreme treeview nodes as links so open in tab is possible

Tags: reactjs, devextreme

would it be possible to make `devextreme treeview` nodes be links so I could open them in a browser's tab if needed? (working with the react version)

currently they are shown as divs with class `dx-item dx-treeview-item`

checked documentation here but can't find any prop for this purpose https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Components/dxTreeView/ but to no avail

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

From the height of my little experience with devextreme.
I did that by setting item template in column metadata.

For example, using typescript I define template name to field:

```
//getting field from metadata by some predicate 
const linkField = meta.find(field => field.searchFlg);
//assign template
if (linkField )
   actionField.cellTemplate = 'myLinkTemplate';
```

And put template handler inside tag <dx-tree-view>

```
<div *dxTemplate="let cellInfo of 'myLinkTemplate'">
  <a title="Go to myLink" (click)="onMyLinkClick(cellInfo)">
    {{ cellInfo.value }}
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [itemTemplate](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Components/dxTreeView/Configuration/#itemTemplate) or [itemRender](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Components/dxTreeView/Configuration/#itemRender) properties to render items as links.

Demo: https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/TreeView/ItemSelectionAndCustomization/React/Light/